# Eliminar una linea dentro de un Arraylist para modificar un archivo

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas para borrar una linea de un archivo.

Como se puede ver en el código de abajo se pide que se inserte el nombre del producto que se desea eliminar para luego borrarse la linea completa, el problema radica en que, el código ya de por sí, comprueba si getNombre coincide con alguno de los nombres de los otros productos, este, de coincidir en vez de borrar esa linea, borra todas las demas que estén despues.

```
case 7: //Eliminar
                    System.out.println("Inserte el nombre del producto que desea borrar: ");
                    String nombreB = sc.next();

                    try {
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ar));
                        for(Proyecto_Inventario n:lista){  
                          if(!n.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreB)){
                           bw.write("Nombre: "+n.getNombre()+"\t"
                                    +"Precio: "+n.getPrecio()+"\t"
                                    +"Descripcion: "+n.getDesc()+"\t"
                                    +"Cantidad: "+n.getCant()+"\t"
                                    +"Almacen: "+n.getAlm()+"\r\n");
                        }else{
                          System.out.println("el producto ha sido eliminado");
                        }
                        bw.close();
                        lista.clear();
                        TransTXTtoObject();
                        } 
                    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
break;
```

---

```
case 7: //Eliminar
                System.out.println("Inserte el nombre del producto que desea borrar: ");
                String nombreB = sc.next();

                try {
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ar));
                    for(Proyecto_Inventario n:lista){  
                      if(!n.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreB)){
                       bw.write(n.getNombre()+"\t"
                               +n.getPrecio()+"\t"
                               +n.getDesc()+"\t"
                               +n.getCant()+"\t"
                               +n.getAlm()+"\r\n");
                    }else{
                      System.out.println("El producto ha sido eliminado");
                        }                          
                    } 
                    bw.close();
                    lista.clear();
                    TransTXTtoObject();

                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería más fácil si borras el elemento de la lista y después vuelves a escribir toda la lista en el fichero.

Te recomiendo que uses un HashTable. De esta manera, tienes una llave con la que poder identificar a los productos(puede ser el nombre) y puedes borrar con mucha más rapidez sin tener que recorrer nada.

Si quieres continuar con tú método la condición debería ser:

```
if (!n.getNombre().equals(nombreB)){
...
}
```